# Toggleable Tabs: Default tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

for my application I wanted to only have one html doc so I used toggleable tabs by following the tutorial of W3School (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp). So I could perfectly have my to tabs, but the default tab 'Homepage' doesn't work. Each time that I actualize the page I have a 'blank' screen.

Here is the code (I tried to cut down the useless html stuff):

```js
function openTab(event, pageName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
  event.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
// Get the element with id="DefaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("DefaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

input,
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

label {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#OrderCreateShipStock>div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 5px;
  border: solid;
}

#OrderCreateShipStock {
  display: inline-table;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

.Order_Create,
.Order_Ship,
.Order_Store {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px;
}

#SubmitCreateOrder,
#SubmitShipOrder,
#SubmitStoreOrder {
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #4caf50;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: auto;
}

#SubmitCreateOrder:hover {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
}

#SubmitShipOrder:hover {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
}

#SubmitStoreOrder:hover {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
}

thead,
tfoot {
  background-color: #3f87a6;
  color: #fff;
}

tbody {
  background-color: #e4f0f5;
}

caption {
  padding: 10px;
  caption-side: bottom;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: .8rem;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid rgb(190, 190, 190);
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

.Horizontal_Tab button {
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.Horizontal_Tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.Horizontal_Tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.Horizontal_Tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15%;
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

._Links {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.Dapp_Links {
  flex: 15%;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Dapp_Links img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.Support_Links {
  flex: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Support_Links img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="HorizontalTab" class="Horizontal_Tab">
    <button id="TabLinks" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'DefaultOpen')">Homepage</button>
    <button id="TabLinks" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'OrderCreateShipStock')">Orders</button>
    <button id="TabLinks" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'OrderList')">Orders list</button>
    <button id="TabLinks" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'OrderWarehouse')">Warehouse list</button>
    <button id="TabLinks" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'OrderShipment')">Shipment list</button>
    <button id="TabLinks" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'OrderOutOfCompliance')">Out of compliance
            list</button>
    <button id="TabLinks" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Support')">Supports</button>
  </div>

  <div id="DefaultOpen" class="tabcontent">
    <h1>Welcome *Account*! You're now logged in as a *Position* at SupChain</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="OrderCreateShipStock" class="tabcontent">

    <div id="OrderCreate" class="Order_Create">
      <h1>Orders</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="OrderShip" class="Order_Ship">
      <h1>OrderShip</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="OrderStore" class="Order_Store">
      <h1>OrderStore</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="OrderList" class="tabcontent">
    <h2>Orders list</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="OrderWarehouse" class="tabcontent">
    <h2>Warehouse</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="OrderShipment" class="tabcontent">
    <h2>Shipments</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="OrderOutOfCompliance" class="tabcontent">
    <h2>Out of compliance</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="Support" class="tabcontent">
    <h1>A problem ? Contact us !</h1>
    <div id="Links" class="_Links">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I don't know where is my error, I re-read the tutorial and my stuff a few times but nothing :/. Moreover, beside this default page everything else is working...
So I would like to request some help please.

I thank in advance anybody who would take the time to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you're running into here is that the `onclick` property is set on the `#TabLinks` button element, but the `.click()` function call is running on the `#DefaultOpen` element.

To resolve this, you'll need to change which element you're targeting with your `.click()` call. Note that this will require changing the ids on your buttons from all being `#TabLinks` to something unique for each one.

[Element ids should always be unique,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

> The id global attribute defines an identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document.

If you ever need to target more than one element at a time, you should use [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class).

```js
function openTab(event, pageName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
  event.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
// Get the element with id="DefaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("TabLinks_DefaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

input,
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

label {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#OrderCreateShipStock>div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 5px;
  border: solid;
}

#OrderCreateShipStock {
  display: inline-table;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

.Order_Create,
.Order_Ship,
.Order_Store {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px;
}

#SubmitCreateOrder,
#SubmitShipOrder,
#SubmitStoreOrder {
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #4caf50;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: auto;
}

#SubmitCreateOrder:hover {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
}

#SubmitShipOrder:hover {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
}

#SubmitStoreOrder:hover {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
}

thead,
tfoot {
  background-color: #3f87a6;
  color: #fff;
}

tbody {
  background-color: #e4f0f5;
}

caption {
  padding: 10px;
  caption-side: bottom;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: .8rem;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid rgb(190, 190, 190);
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

.Horizontal_Tab button {
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.Horizontal_Tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.Horizontal_Tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.Horizontal_Tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15%;
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

._Links {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.Dapp_Links {
  flex: 15%;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Dapp_Links img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.Support_Links {
  flex: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Support_Links img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="HorizontalTab" class="Horizontal_Tab">
    <button id="TabLinks_DefaultOpen" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'DefaultOpen')">Homepage</button>
    <button id="TabLinks_OrderCreateShipStock" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'OrderCreateShipStock')">Orders</button>
    <button id="TabLinks_OrderList" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'OrderList')">Orders list</button>
    <button id="TabLinks_OrderWarehouse" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'OrderWarehouse')">Warehouse list</button>
    <button id="TabLinks_OrderShipment" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'OrderShipment')">Shipment list</button>
    <button id="TabLinks_OrderOutOfCompliance" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'OrderOutOfCompliance')">Out of compliance
            list</button>
    <button id="TabLinks_Support" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Support')">Supports</button>
  </div>

  <div id="DefaultOpen" class="tabcontent">
    <h1>Welcome *Account*! You're now logged in as a *Position* at SupChain</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="OrderCreateShipStock" class="tabcontent">

    <div id="OrderCreate" class="Order_Create">
      <h1>Orders</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="OrderShip" class="Order_Ship">
      <h1>OrderShip</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="OrderStore" class="Order_Store">
      <h1>OrderStore</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="OrderList" class="tabcontent">
    <h2>Orders list</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="OrderWarehouse" class="tabcontent">
    <h2>Warehouse</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="OrderShipment" class="tabcontent">
    <h2>Shipments</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="OrderOutOfCompliance" class="tabcontent">
    <h2>Out of compliance</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="Support" class="tabcontent">
    <h1>A problem ? Contact us !</h1>
    <div id="Links" class="_Links">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Let me know if you would like me to clarify anything or if you have any questions!